# Share Same Game Center Leaderboard iOS / tvOS / OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, game-center, tvos, game-center-leaderboard

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to somehow share the leaderboard / achievements from say an iOS game center leaderboard, to be used as well for say tvOS and OS X versions of the same game?

Or does each seperate platform have to maintain their own clone of the same leaderboard /  achievements?

If this is possible any links to reference material would be awesome, I can't find anything bar the mention of something like this being possible in the tvOS Keynote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions: One for iOS / tvOS, and one for all three.

According to amandavoss from Apple

> For iOS and TVOS you can use the new "universal bundle ID" feature
>   where you can add a TVOS version of the app to the existing iOS bundle
>   ID. In iTunes Connect you would just go to the iOS app in question and
>   in the App Store view click + Version. Select TVOS and go from there.
>
> Another option would be to group them games. This would add "grp." to 
>   all leaderboard and achievement identifiers but can be shared by all
>   apps in the group (where each app has a unique bundle ID). For that
>   simple "Move to Group" in iTunes Connect.
>
> amandavoss

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24514

Answer (score 2):

For iOS and TVOS this is possible, if they use the same BundleID.

If you have an existing iOS project just open iTunes Connect. Hit the '+' button to add an Apple TV version. Both will share their leaderboards.

[image]